# what's (page = DEFAULT_PAGE) role in CustomPagination by DRF (django-rest-framework)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination, paginator

For some reason, I could not understand the meaning and role of `page=DEFAULT_PAGE` in Custom Pagination in the **DRF** topic. Can you explain its role to me in the code below?

Consider - pagination.py:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response


DEFAULT_PAGE = 9
DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 9

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page = DEFAULT_PAGE
    page_size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page': int(self.request.GET.get('page', DEFAULT_PAGE)), # can not set default = self.page
            'page_size': int(self.request.GET.get('page_size', self.page_size)),
            'results': data
        })
```

**Note** : This is important to me for setting up my app and I wanted to understand its role... Although I consulted the documentation, I didn't understand much about the role of `page=PAGE_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `page = DEFAULT_PAGE` define a default page number (9 in your example) for the DRF custom pagination class.
When the client doesn't specify one in the request, it ensures a fallback for pagination.